# numpy. Sum multidimensional array at specific indexes

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I'm trying to replace something like this code, for a vectorized efficient operation using numpy.

```
counter = 0
idxs = [1, 3]
lists = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
for l in lists:
    for idx in idxs:
        counter += l[idx]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just sum the array:

```
idxs = [1, 3]
lists = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
ary = np.array(lists)
counter = ary[:,idxs].sum()
```